# Supply Voltage of the Instrumentation Amplifier INA332 from TI

Tags: instrumentation

At page 2 on top left there is written "Supply Voltage, V+ to V- ......... 7,5 V"

[Low-Power, Single-Supply, CMOS INSTRUMENTATION AMPLIFIERS](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1964153.pdf)

Is that the supply *range*? Or is it meant like maximum V+ = 7,5 V and V- = 7,5 V (*range* would be 15 V)?

I can't figure it out with the data sheet. Will be grateful for any help!

Greets,
keep

Comment: The voltage drop from V+ to V- can be no more than 7.5V, that means you could have [V+ at 7.5V and V- at 0V ] OR [ V+ at 3.5V and V- at -4V ] OR [ V+ at 0V and V- at -7.5V ] and still be in the limit of the absolute maximum ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that the (algebraic) difference between V+ and V- has to be 7.5 V. It doesn't matter, in principle, what is the value of V+ and V- with respect to ground.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Page 3 of datasheet.*

The big clue for intended use is on the top of page 3. As others have said, this can be a split-rail power supply provided \$ V_+ - V_- < 7.5~V \$.

If running on split supplies you need to take particular care (just because it would be easy to make a mistake) not to exceed the limits on the inputs. The rule applies on single voltage supplies too but usually you will be running from a supply common to all the other chips so out-of-range signals would be more difficult to generate.

[image]

*Figure 2. Note that the maximum signal input is \$ V_+ + 0.5V \$ and minimum is \$ V_- - 0.5V \$.*

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. :-) How did you cut the first figure so nicely?

Comment: Greenshot open source screen capture for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a single supply part, it means that (V+ - V-) <= 7.5V
If you would use dual supplies, it would translate to +-3.75V.

However, this Instrumentation Amp is designed for single supply, which you can also see by the specified supply range (page 3): Specified Voltage Range (min..max) +2.7 .. +5.5 V.
You can use it with dual supply but would have a very limited +-1.35..+-2.25V supply voltage to stay within device specs.

The absolute maximum ratings just ensure the part is not damaged permanently, they do not ensure that the part stays within specifications.